# Failed to export vector file from OGR?

Tags: ogr, error, coordinate-system, wgs84

I use to transform data points from UTM (WGS84) to WGS84 EPSG:4326. Basically from UTM to Geographic coordinate system both in (WGS84). I tried to do it again but an error message appears.

Translation:

> Failed to export vector file. Error: Error writing object: Error
>   creating space object ( OGR error : Failed to create ./A.csv :
>   Permission denied )

Original:

> Falló la exportación a archivo vectorial. Error: Errores de escritura
>   de objeto espacial: Error de creación de objeto espacial (error de
>   OGR: Failed to create ./A.csv: Permission denied)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact command

Answer (score 1):

You are either trying to write the CSV to a path for which you don't have permission, or some other process is locking the CSV (you have it open in Excel etc...)

Comment: I used to do the same task many times, the difference is that I update the iOS from Lion to El Capitan, after that i have issues . ¿What can i do?

Comment: I fix it up, i uninstall QGis and the libraries and i installed again, and wok it out. ¡Thanks a lot anyway!